# Telnet:WiFi with Telnet-Strange Result while connected

Tags: terminal, wifi, port, telnet, mts

Few days ago I bought a new MTS Wi-Fi Dongle, today while using it, I did a port scan on 192.168.1.1 using my Android device and surprisingly port 23(telnet) was open. After typing telnet 192.168.1.1, below was the result on window of terminal,
VENKY V2.0 Welcome You!!!

VENKY>

and after sometime, it started showing following message,
^HRSSILVL : 60
^HRSSILVL : 80
^HRSSILVL : 60

and so on, I tried few Linux commands(I know it wont work but still) but none of them worked, one I have figured out is ***version*** command, which shows version, Does anyone know what VENKY is or has encountered something same....?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a command line interface for your Huawei usb modem.

You may try running an `AT` command like `^TIME`, `&V` or `^OTAACTED` and so on.

The `HRSSILVL^:<rssi>` reports the received signal strength.

Here is a manual page that might be useful: [Huawei MC509 User's Manual Page 65](http://www.manualguru.com/huawei/mc509/users-manual)